# Trigger virt-sysprep with Terraform on RHEL VM on vSphere

Tags: redhat, terraform, vsphere

I am domain-joining a RHEL VM in vSphere for automated patching reasons. This VM will serve as the template for my Terraform builds. I need to clean up this VM during my Terraform run, and virt-sysprep seems like the best candidate. I'm wondering if there are established patterns for triggering actions on the vSphere host through Terraform?

Comment: There is the remote exec provisioner that will execute commands over SSH or other types of connection (eg WinRM)